# Grayscale and Alpha Mask in Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, masking

I would like to make a mask that both converts any colors to grayscale and then reduces their alpha value. The intended purpose is for the masked region to be in grayscale and lighter so that the unmasked region is more prominent. Most tutorials I've seen for alpha value masks are far too complicated and use the Flash GUI. How do you accomplish the same thing in ActionScript?

**Update:** Here's an explanation with pictures...

If the following is my image:

[image]

Then a traditional mask over some selection would produce the following:

[image]

Instead, those parts that are masked out completely, I would like for those to be converted to grayscale:

[image]

And their alpha value decreased, so they're lightened:

[image]

Comment: i really don't follow what you are trying to do.  "the part that usually is shown with a normal mask" is throwing me off.  you want 2 masks on an image?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation :

1. Create an instance of Sprite / Movieclip you want to mask over as a BitmapData object
2. Create a Mask instance that you apply to the Sprite Movieclip
3. Create a duplicate instance of the sprite / movieclip original that's of type BitmapData class. You duplicate this using [copyPixels](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29) method and making sure it's the same width + height.
4. Create a 3rd instance of the original, this time with an alpha property applied to it, but it's visible property set to "none".
5. On the duplicate (2nd) instance, you can include this 3rd instance as a source for the alpha properties in the copyPixels arguments
6. Apply a [ColorMatrixFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html#includeExamplesSummary) to the 2nd instance to achieve your grayscale. It also accepts an alpha property if you don't want to use *step 5* but your example looks like the alpha isn't the same everywhere, hence requiring the 3rd instance

I hope this helps. And if you're still not sure, just watch Primer.